# Problem while scanning a char and float simultaneously

Tags: c, arrays, types

I am trying to take five character and 5 float input.

```
main()  
{    
char c[5];    
float q[5];    
int i;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)  
{   
        printf("\n%d ",i);  
    scanf("%c",c+i);   
    scanf("%f",q+i);  
    }  
}
```

But the output is absurd. After two sequential scans, it skips third scan and then again skips fifth scan.
I am not able to understand why is it showing such a behaviour.
I am working on gcc compiler.

Answer (score 2):

[Use of scanf is not recommended](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) because of problems like this.

Instead use `fgets` to read the entire line and then use `sscanf` to extract what you want(a `char` or a `float`) from the line just read:

```
    char line[MAX];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
            if( fgets(line,MAX,stdin) && sscanf(line,"%c", c+i)!=1 )
                    *(c+i) = 0;
            if( fgets(line,MAX,stdin) && sscanf(line,"%f", q+i)!=1 )
                    *(q+i) = 0.0;
            printf("%c %f\n",*(c+i),*(q+i));

    }
```

Comment: I am not able to find the reason for such a behaviour of my code. Can you please explain it to me.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer why the 3rd and every other scan "skips", it is the way `scanf()` and the `%c` format works.  When there is a call to `scanf()`, you typically have to press enter to "submit" the input.  Consequently that inserts a newline character into the `stdin` stream.

When the previous float scan got inputted, the newline is still left in the stream. When the character scan gets reached, that remaining newline character is read in since it fits effectively "skipping" the call.

You *should* use `fgets()` with `sscanf()` as codaddict suggests.

But as a quick fix, you could try adding a call to `getchar()` after the float scan to consume that newline character from the stream.

**edit:**
You're saying this doesn't work?  (assuming you input the correct kinds of values, one per scanf call)

```
main()
{
    char c[5];
    float q[5];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d ",i);
        scanf("%c",c+i);
        scanf("%f",q+i);
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: even the getchar() thing is not working. I even used fflush(stdin), but still the result is same.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
    int main(){
    char c[6];//char array size must be 6 to store five charecter
              //as null-terminator('\0')will use the last one
    float q[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            printf("\n%d\n",i);fflush(stdout);
            scanf("%c",&c[i]);fflush(stdin);//fflush(stdin) to clear input stream that
                                            //next scanf() won't skip
            scanf("%f",&q[i]);fflush(stdin);//fflush(stdin) to clear input stream that
                                            //scanf() won't skip at new loop
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`fflush()` is not defined on an input stream, like `stdin`.  Don't do it.

If you want to "read and discard until newline", then do:

```
int ch;
do {
    ch = getchar();
} while (ch != EOF && ch != '\n');
```

Note that `%c` means "read the next character in the input stream, even if it's whitespace, then stop".  `%f` means "read and discard whitespace, then try to read a float from the input stream, then stop."

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this :

```
main()  
{    
char c[5];    
float q[5];    
int i;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)  
{   
        printf("\n%d ",i);  
    scanf("%c",c+i);
    while (getchar()!='\n');   
    scanf("%f",q+i);
    while (getchar()!='\n');   
    }  
}
```

the sentence `while (getchar()!='\n');` search till the end of input, so it would not take '\n' as an input value for q+i.Also another `while (getchar()!='\n');` after scanf q+i,since you use loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** in scanning a char value after a float value.

**Solution is very simple!!!**

instead of writting your code like this

```
scanf("%c",&...)
```

try this,

```
scanf(" %c",&...)
```

**A Space** before the"%c" will resolve the problem by neglecting the value of the Return(Enter) key when pressed after typing the value of the float as an input.

> When a float value is scanned before a character value.
>   The value obtained by pressing the Return(Enter) key is collected in the following char variable. Using a space before(" %c",&...) discards the value collected of the Return(Enter) Key, Causing the Char value to be scanned in the next line. Thus solving **The Scanning Float-Char problem.**